# Generating series for powers of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

Denote $(f_n)_n$ the Fibonacci numbers and $(l_n)_n$ the Lucas numbers. The definition is such that 
$$
\begin{array}{lll} f_0 = 0,& f_1= 1,& f_{n+2}=f_{n+1}+f_n,\\
l_0 = 2,& l_1=1, &
l_{n+2}=l_{n+1}+l_n.
\end{array}
$$

Define formal series 
$$F_{k}(x) :=  \sum_{n\geq 0} f_{k(n+1)}x^n
\quad \text{and} \quad
 L_k(x) := \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \frac{1}{1-x},& k=0, \\
\sum_{n\geq 0 } l_{k(n+1)}x^n, &k>0. \end{array}\right.
$$

Prove that, for all $p\geq 0$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n\geq 0} f^{2p}_{n+1}x^n =& \frac{1}{5^p}\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{2p}{p-k}L_{2k}((-1)^{p-k}x) ,
\\
\\
\sum_{n\geq 0} f^{2p+1}_{n+1}x^n = &\frac{1}{5^p}\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{2p+1}{p-k}F_{2k+1}((-1)^{p-k}x) .
\end{eqnarray}

My interest in that formula comes from the fact that 
$$ 
F_{2k+1}(x) = \frac{f_{2k+1}}{1-l_{2k+1}x-x^2}\quad \text{and} \quad
L_{2k}(x) = \frac{l_{2k}-2x}{1-l_{2k}x+x^2},
$$
thus giving the generating series as a rational function, from which a recurrence relation for Fibonacci powers can be read off.

It is known that Fibonacci powers for a fixed exponent must satisfy a finite recurrence relation, check out http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/Fibonomials.html. However I have no idea on how to prove this precise formula.

**Edit:** As Phira mentioned and I forgot to check, it is easily proven using Binet's formula, but a proof that makes no use of irrational numbers would be nice.

Comment: Where did you get stuck in your attempt?  Please show the work you tried prior to getting stuck.

Comment: It is known that Fibonacci powers for a fixed exponent must satisfy a finite recurrence relation, check out [http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/Fibonomials.html](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/Fibonomials.html). However I have no idea on how to prove this precise formula.

Comment: Remark: the formula generalizes https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1502690/301936, using that $F_k(x)=\frac{f_k}{1-l_kx-x^2} $ and $L_k(x)=\frac{l_k-2x}{1-l_kx+x^2}$, for $k>0$.

Comment: Just plug in the formula with the golden ratio on the left side.

Comment: @Phira Oh thanks, Binet's formula does the job. I should have tried this before.